# how to get through spam filters?

Tags: email, email-bounces

I sent 3 emails last week as replies from our website. None received them! One was yahoo, hotmail and an overseas domain. I am wondering if it's not a good idea to open a yahoo account with our domain name as the user just to reply to prospective buyers.

Answer (score 1):

Your mail server's IP may have been black listed.  This is common on shared servers. 
http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, check [dnsbl.info](http://www.dnsbl.info/advanced.asp) to see if your mailserver's IP is blocked by any of the blacklists. If they are, contact the blacklist administrator to investigate removing the block.

Answer (score 1):

If your email is business critical, then you need to get a dedicated server with a white-hat hosting company, control over DNS to set up your SPF/SenderID record, and to register with the Hotmail, AOL and Yahoo postmasters for whitelisting and feedback loops.  Most of these will only accept requests for dedicated servers, where you have 100% control over the email they send.

If you are using an online contact form, make people double-enter their email address and check the entries match - otherwise you'll have no end of typos, which are naturally undeliverable and frustrating for both you and your customers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try looking at [gmail for domains](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html). It's what I use and so far I haven't had a problem withany spam filters. Also make sure that you are not writing the content of the message to where a spam filter could flag it as spam. There's some guides on the net somewhere. I found out that by removing the word "free" from the message the emails started going though (before I was on gmail).